# Value of "nonresearch articles" section in PNAS

Tags: publications, early-career

I noticed that [PNAS](http://www.pnas.org) website contains the section for the so-called *"nonresearch articles"* (original orthography is retained), otherwise referred to as *"collected articles"*: http://www.pnas.org/site/misc/collectedpapers.xhtml. Upon a brief look at the section and its categories, it seems that articles published there range from "core concepts" articles (somewhat similar to a brief Wikipedia article) to a topic or field review articles and beyond (papers, based on symposiums and other events).

My **question** is twofold:

- what is the *level of acceptance*, if known, for articles, targeting the above-mentioned section;
- what is the *scientific, academic and career value* of publishing in that PNAS' section (in other words, is it worth considering targeting this outlet [particularly, for a *beginning researcher*])?

Comment: Please note that this question is _different_ from [my other question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/52693/12391) on publishing in _PNAS_ in that the former is about publishing _in a specific section_ of the publishing outlet, whereas the latter is concerned with publishing there _in general_.

Answer (score 4):

I had a look at the latest collection paper (*[Megafauna and ecosystem function from the Pleistocene to the Anthropocene](http://www.pnas.org/content/113/4/838.abstract)*). This turned out to be a [PNAS Direct Submission](http://www.pnas.org/site/aboutpnas/submiss.xhtml), which appears to be a pretty standard peer-review process and definitely the standard way to submit papers to PNAS ("Direct Submissions now account for more than 95% of papers submitted and 78% of papers published in PNAS"). I couldn't find out any sort of invitation for collected papers, so my guess is that these are papers that have **already been published through standard peer-review**, which have been grouped after the fact by PNAS editors. So this isn't a "PNAS section", but just a thematic collection of papers that have been normally published in PNAS (which, in 2014, had an [acceptance rate of 17%](http://www.pnas.org/content/111/40/14311.full)).

Comment: I appreciate your nice answer (+1). It has valuable information and insights. However, I suspect that your conclusions might be applicable only to certain, but not all domains, represented in PNAS. Hopefully, my question will pick up some additional interest (I have posted a small bounty for it, but, ironically, it has expired just yesterday) and people from other domains could clarify the situation in this regard. Again, thank you for your feedback.